# Not able to compile comments in SASS

Tags: sass

I'm using Mac 10.7.2, Ruby 1.9.3, and SASS 3.2.1. I'm trying to get multiline comment and comments between multilevel CSS. I know we can achieve multiline comment in SASS as below:

**SASS**

```
/*
 Multiline
 comments
 goes here
```

**CSS**

```
/* Multiline
 * comments
 * goes here */
```

But i use different kinda comments in my style sheet to highlight/identify multiple levels and different kinda stuff in my CSS two of them are below:

My style sheet start with comment below:

```
/***************************************************************

Theme Name: Theme name goes here
Theme URI: Theme URL goes here
Description: Discription related to theme will goes here
Version: 1.1
Author: Author name goes here
Author URI: Authour url goes here

***************************************************************/
```

My application Index comment are like below:

```
/*
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
--- Table of Contents:              ---
---                                 ---
--- 1. HEADER                       ---
--- -1.1 Navigation Bar             ---
---                                 ---
---                                 ---
--- 2. MAIN SECTION                 ---
--- -2.1 Home page                  ---
--- --2.1.1 Sections                ---
--- ---2.1.1.1 sub section          ---
---                                 ---
---                                 ---
--- 3. FOOTER                       ---
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
*/
```

I can find comment closer to it but, not able to get exactly this as compiled CSS comment

**SASS**

```
/*
  ---------------------------------------
  ---------------------------------------
  --- Table of Contents:              ---
  ---                                 ---
  --- 1. DEFAULT ELEMENTS             ---
  --- 2. LINKS                        ---
  --- 3. TABLE                        ---
  --- 4. FORM                         ---
  --- 5. GLOBAL CLASSES               ---
  ---------------------------------------
  ---------------------------------------
```

**CSS**

```
/*  ---------------------------------------
 *  ---------------------------------------
 *  --- Table of Contents:              ---
 *  ---                                 ---
 *  --- 1. DEFAULT ELEMENTS             ---
 *  --- 2. LINKS                        ---
 *  --- 3. TABLE                        ---
 *  --- 4. FORM                         ---
 *  --- 5. GLOBAL CLASSES               ---
 *  ---------------------------------------
 *  --------------------------------------- */
```

Also some time we need comments in multilevel

```
.firstLavel
  background: #f00
  /* comeent goes here before second level */
  .secondLavel
    font-size:  20
    color:  #ddd
  /* comeent goes here before third level
  .secondLavel
    font-size:  70
    color:  #ded
```

But I'm getting result:

```
  background: red;
  /* comeent goes here before second level */
  /* comeent goes here before third level */ }
  .firstLavel .secondLavel {
    font-size: 20;
    color: #dddddd; }
  .firstLavel .secondLavel {
    font-size: 70;
    color: #ddeedd; }
```

It should be:

```
.firstLavel {
  background: red; }

  /* comment goes here before second level */
  .firstLavel .secondLavel {
    font-size: 20;
    color: #dddddd; }

  /* comment goes here before third level */ 
  .firstLavel .secondLavel {
    font-size: 70;
    color: #ddeedd; }
```

Comment: Just a question, since there is no debate that all production CSS should be minified, why not use `//` Sass comments so you can have comments for yourself and your team but your users don't have to download them?

Comment: Yes i totally agree, But in my case i want to keep both in my application and i'll use minified in production. Some time my team or others don't have Ruby or SASS compiler. So they can at least make change in CSS.

Comment: Any change they make to the CSS will be overwritten the next time you compile. If you want to use Sass, you need everyone on board.

Comment: Can you use SCSS syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Sass compiles using a algorithm that recursively renders all children of the CSS tree, starting with the endpoints (those without deeper levels). 
Due to this algorithm it won't be possible to set a comment before a child when it is not an endpoint: comments never have deeper levels.. The only way to set comments is set the comment as a child of the node.

To clarify, consider this tree:

```
root
  child1 
    child1.1
      /* comment on 1.1*/
      child1.1.1
    child1.2
  child2
  /* comment on 2 */
  child3
    /* comment on 3*/
    child3.1
  child4
```

rendering it will result first the entries without children, afterwards the entries those that go deeper.
The order of the CSS will be:

```
root
  child2
  /* comment on 2 */
  child4
  child1
    child1.2
    child1.1
      /* comment on 1.1 */
      child1.1.1
  child3
    /* comment on 3 */
    child3.1
```

Algorithm used is a [BSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) with a queue which puts endpoints first

Comment: Yeah, it kinda sucks.. You can always help with the development of SASS and add comment functionality ;)

Comment: SASS have their own comment which is great for maintenance purpose in future. But I'm looking for CSS comment, Because In case someone else work on it in future, don't have ruby compiler. He/she can use uncompressed CSS in that case.